# Appropriate Widget and/or Layout for a Game in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I’m trying to develop a game that allows a player to drag playing cards from their hand to a location on an open table

Cards can only be dragged and dropped to certain positions adjacent to a card that was played prior.   The valid locations are either vertical or horizontal from the last played card, unless it’s the first card and it can be dropped anywhere.  I’d like the adjacent locations that are valid for dropping a card to be highlighted in green when it’s the user’s turn as illustrated below:

[image]

Would I need to use the CustomPainter class to handle this situation?   If so, should I make the entire Custom Painter area a drop target and have it update appropriately when dragging?

Looking for ideas/input.  Thanks.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I planned on wrapping the cards with Draggable.

I'm thinking more about how to make the playfield as shown in the image. I was wondering if a gridview layout would work, but the more I think about it, it almost feels like I need a more custom layout to be able to position cards where I want them. It's not a row / column layout. I might be able to use something custom that positions the cards using stacked. The thing I don't like about stacked is that the cards would potentially be on top of each other. It might be OK, since the cards on a table might do the same thing.